# Need some pointers regarding JSON formatting for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON that I am trying to use for a highcharts chart. Current I get nothing output in the chart (data), although I do see all four "questions" in the legend.

```
    [
    {
        "name": "Question 1",
        "data": [
            "1391981824000, 2",
            "1391981874000, 2",
            "1391981966000, 4",
            "1391982000000, 1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Question 2",
        "data": [
            "1391981830000, 3",
            "1391981878000, 4",
            "1391981971000, 2",
            "1391982005000, 2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Question 3",
        "data": [
            "1391981837000, 1",
            "1391981885000, 1",
            "1391981977000, 1",
            "1391982010000, 3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Question 4",
        "data": [
            "1391981842000, 4",
            "1391981898000, 3",
            "1391981982000, 3",
            "1391982015000, 4"
        ]
    }
]
```

And the javascript for the chart:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("mysql/getChartData.php?sd=2012-02-09%2015:36:42&ed=2016-02-09%2016:37:39", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'custom-range-line',
                    type: 'line'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Custom Date Range',
                    x: -20
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Ratings'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 2
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});
```

What am I doing wrong/why wouldn't this work?  I've found a ton of example of how to do this, but none quite the way I need it. Let me know if there's anything else I can show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data needs to be an array of tuples like so: For the UNIX timestamps, they need to be numeric, you currently have them as strings. It looks like you have correctly multiplied the UNIX timestamp * 1000 in order to work in JavaScript. Be assured that the value of `options.data` is an array so you can add more sets to it. Try it with one first, then gradually increase it so you can get used to the HighCharts API.

```
 var options = {
    "data": {[
        [1391981824000, 2],
        [1391981874000, 2],
        [1391981966000, 4],
        [1391982000000, 3],
     ]}
 }
```

Comment: I do not have control over your source data, I just can tell you the required syntax.

Comment: Yeah, just saying. Might be syntactically correct but not logically.

Comment: It's your data. If your graph is not a function, then you need to reevaluate your x-values. of what you are trying to measure.

Comment: I'm not the original poster.